# Open Sans letter spacing in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, typography

In Google Chrome (49.0.2623.87 m) when I use `letter-spacing` with the `Open Sans` font, there is no letter spacing between `fi`. ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aLctr9oa/))

Is there a (JS/CSS/HTML) workaround for it?

(I need both open sans and letter-spacing... And `fi` letterpair too.)

**EDIT**:
Appeard on Windows 10, Chrome

Comment: Just tried it on MacOsX Safari / Chrome / FF and no problem the letter-spacing is working

Comment: Yep, it works everywhere except Chrome. What is the version of your chrome?

Comment: That’s called a [Typographic Ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature). Not all browsers/font rendering mechanisms support it; but I think there are some not yet standardized CSS properties to disable such Open Type(?) features. If not or those don’t work, you may need to create a variant of your web font(?) that does not include those.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 48. So your problem seems to be on Chrome + Windows. It's weird cause Open Sans is a very common font now.

Comment: So Windows with Chrome with Open Sans is the only what seems to support this "amazing" feature? OMG. I'm a very lucky person.

Comment: Please tell me that why did I get the downvote.

Comment: This could be considered a WebKit bug? I'm seeing this with latest Safari too, on MBP retina 13 (screen resolution set to looks like 1440x900), and even if the font is not Open Sans https://www.dropbox.com/s/c1dixlhg88dld3t/Screenshot%202016-03-13%2019.52.27.png?dl=0

Comment: As @CBroe mensioned, it's not a bug - these are ligatures (also ff, ffi, ffl, fl, etc.). You can turn it off with the amazing `font-variant-ligatures: no-common-ligatures;` property value pair (You may need webkit prefix for Safari).

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @CBroe I found the solution.

It's not a bug, it's more like a feature leading to more organized text ([Typographic ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature)). In some cases this can be very irritating, so there is an easy way to turn it off with CSS: `font-variant-ligatures: no-common-ligatures;`.

It deactivates these ligatures.

Read more at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-ligatures

**EDIT**:
Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aLctr9oa/3/